# Is there any way to do a plain text regex find and replace with standard Windows software?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, regex

[Long story short](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36168/is-there-any-way-to-set-fallback-font-families-in-illustrator-svg), I need to enable a client to routinely run a regex find and replace that looks like this on many SVG files that are up to 3mbs in size:

- Find: `font-family=".*?"`
- Replace with: `font-family="Liberation Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"`

Easy in most code editors: but the problem is, the employees who will be doing this process will be on a **very restricted environment** - Windows 7 with essentially no non-standard software except Microsoft Office and possibly Adobe Illustrator, on [virtual desktops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization) with no admin rights. This seems to be non-negotiable, unfortunately.

I'm trying to make a case for management to make an exception and allow something like Notepad++ to be added to their environment - but this isn't as simple as it sounds (as I understand it, because it's virtualised, installing custom software to one machine means installing it to the servers that 1,000+ machines use, which they're very resistant to do).

So assuming installing custom software isn't possible, is there any way to do a simple regex find / replace using tools that come with Windows or Office?

I'm aware of Word having some regex find/replace capabilities, but not aware of any way to stop it also making a mess of any code file it touches. There are many other little tools packaged with Windows: can any of them do this? Web-based tools could also work.

Comment: check to see if Powershell is installed, if so can it execute powershell scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually a lot of options..

This online tool is great --> http://www.regexr.com/

Also, you could download NOTEPAD++ portable version and run anyhthing there..

Good luck!

- seems like a dup q -  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084351/online-regex-find-and-replace]

Comment: I saw regexr but couldn't find the "replace" option. Looking at it again, there's a massive bar at the bottom marked "substitution" - should do the job! Will try it

Comment: did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Can they run VBScript? If so, then the following (quickly hacked together) VBScript will work:

```vbs
Option Explicit
If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Usage: " & WScript.ScriptName & " <input> <output>"
    WScript.Quit
End If
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)) = False Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: `" & WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & "` does not exist."
    WScript.Quit
End If
Dim oFile : Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
Dim sContents : sContents = oFile.ReadAll : oFile.Close
Dim re : Set re = New Regexp
re.IgnoreCase = True : re.Global = True : re.Pattern = "font-family=\"".*?\"""
sContents = re.Replace(sContents, "font-family=""Liberation Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif""")
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Item(1), True)
oFile.Write sContents
oFile.Close
Set re = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Save it as something (for example `convert.vbs`) and then run it with the following command line:

```
cscript convert.vbs <input file> <output file>
```

If you want to overwrite the original with the modifications, just put the file name in twice, for example:

```
cscript convert.vbs diagram.svg diagram.svg
```

Depending on your comfort level, you can either modify this to work on a group of files or write a batch file that calls this as many times as there are files.